# Deleted records now I get Entity is deleted on reinsert

Tags: apex, rest-api

I have run the following commands in hope to double check a script

1: List<Culture_TCH__c> oldCultures = [SELECT Id FROM Culture_TCH__c WHERE Assessment_TCH__c = :oldAssessment.Id];

2: delete oldCultures;

But when I insert the same records again I get

```
ENTITY_IS_DELETED:entity is deleted:--
```

do I need to empty my recycle bin or something ? So I can insert the same records ? If so How

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Id value is still in memory. You need to clear out the Id field:

```
List<Culture_TCH__c> oldCultures = [SELECT Id FROM Culture_TCH__c WHERE Assessment_TCH__c = :oldAssessment.Id];
delete oldCultures;
Culture_TCH__c[] newCultures = oldCultures.deepClone(false);
```

The first parameter set to false will clear out the ID values from memory and allow a fresh insert.

Comment: I still get the same issue :(

Comment: @MicahArmantrout without seeing more code, not much more I can do to help. All I know is you're trying to modify a deleted record.

Comment: @sfcfox Totally understand I found that some of the records I removed should not have removed

Comment: Apparently there is more than one reason for this to happen. I was able to recover a record the the recycle bin and fix my issue. This record had a unique value on it that I needed to insert the other records